# Vorticity equation for generalized Naiver Stokes equations

Tags: ap.analysis-of-pdes, elliptic-pde, parabolic-pde, navier-stokes

In $3D$ or $2D$, I can get the vorticity equation for the incompressible NSE; however, what's the vorticity equation for the generalized NSE? Does the fractional laplacian commute with the curl?

Comment: Do you mean in the whole space $\mathbb R^2$ or $\mathbb R^3$ ? (beware: _Navier_)

Comment: @JeanDuchon How to derive the vorticity equation in $\mathbb R^2$?

Answer (score 2):

Taking the curl of the original equation in $\mathbb R^3$ gives$$\partial_t\omega+\nu(-\Delta)^\alpha\omega+(u\cdot\nabla)\omega-(\omega\cdot\nabla) u=\nabla\times f$$ $$\nabla\times u=\omega$$ $$\nabla\cdot u=0$$ $(-\Delta)^\alpha$ and $\nabla\times$ commute in this case ($\mathbb R^3$) because they operate on Fourier transforms as multiplying by $|\xi|^{2\alpha}$ and $i\xi\times$, respectively.

On domains with a boundary, it may depend on the precise definition of $(-\Delta)^\alpha$ and boundary conditions.

In $\mathbb R^2$, $\omega=\nabla\times u$ is a scalar field with$$\partial_t\omega+\nu(-\Delta)^\alpha\omega+(u\cdot\nabla)\omega=\nabla\times f$$